# Неверный перевод сообщения о плохой проверке ответов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

> СТОП! Смотрите и слушайте.
>
> ...
>
> Не волнуйтесь, **мы уже приняли подготовили данное сообщение**.
>
> ...

Данное сообщение появляется, когда система подкидывает заведомо плохие ответы, а пользователь помечает их, как "Ничего делать не нужно".
Я не знаю, что пишется в английской версии SO, но предполагаю, что должно быть что-то типа

> Не волнуйтесь, **мы уже приняли меры для данного сообщения**.

И как слушать? Никакого звука ведь нет. Наверное должно было быть что-то типа

> СТОП! Смотрите и запоминайте.

**Оригиналы строк (ссылка на Transifex) и текущие переводы:**

> ([Tx:3613](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265405?key=bfb64d98ec1d1536b351736497c6c6b1)) STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> СТОП! Смотрите и слушайте.

> ([Tx:3592](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265384?key=1af478fd036562995e659e0f5e404a37)) Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.
>
> Не волнуйтесь, мы уже приняли подготовили данное сообщение. Пожалуйста, уделите минутку и проверьте его внимательно, учитывая вышеприведенные инструкции.

Comment: Похоже, новых вариантов не будет. ) Предлагаю принять ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> СТОП! Читайте и запоминайте.

> Не волнуйтесь, мы уже позаботились об этом сообщении. Пожалуйста, уделите минуту и внимательно изучите его, учитывая вышеприведённые инструкции.

Comment: Пока что применил эти варианты, когда появится лидер голосования - поменяю ещё раз.